# Mass change powercfg on remote computers

Tags: powershell, psexec, powercfg

I'm wondering if there is a way to modify the powercfg script to pull from a list of PC's to change the power settings on many remote computers?

This is the script i'm using now:

psexec \PC-NAME powercfg -change -hibernate-timeout-ac 0

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a single machine name, [PsExec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) can execute the command against a list of servers from a text file:

```
psexec @PCs.txt powercfg -change -hibernate-timeout-ac 0
```

assuming `PCs.txt` is a file in the current directory containing the name of a computer on each line

Comment: @Charles not anymore 